# How do I render a component depending on browser type?

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, jsf-2

I have a web application in which I have certain components that should not be rendered if the browser is Internet Explorer.

I can technically use jquery but I'm assuming that's no good because it's a client side code and the rendered attribute is computed on the server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could check if the `User-Agent` header contains the string `MSIE`. Here's an overview of all "valid" MSIE header strings: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/ You'll see that all MSIE strings share the same pattern `"; MSIE "`. You could check on that:

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!header['User-Agent'].contains('; MSIE ')}">
```

or when you are not on Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 yet:

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!fn:contains(header['User-Agent'], '; MSIE ')}">
```

You however need to be aware that this is a client-controlled value and can easily be changed/spoofed. Doing the checks in the client side using for example conditional comments is much more reliable as MSIE is really the *only* browser which interprets them.

Answer (score 2):

If you can avoid it, I would suggest not trying to do specific stuff for a specific browser. Especially on the server-side, the only way to determine the browser is the `user-agent` string, but this is unreliable - some users may spoof it, others may use privacy software or a proxy which blanks it out entirely. So you really can't be certain of the browser at the server end.

It is far better idea to serve the same code to all browsers, and then do feature detection on the browser itself to determine what browser features are available.

A good feature detection script is [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com). You can use this to customise your site according to what the browser is capable of.

In the case of IE versions 8 and earlier, there are a few cases where Modernizr isn't sufficient, and you simply have to do something different for this browser to get around its bugs. In this case, I recommend using [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) in your HTML code to insert the IE-specific code. Conditional Comments is a feature which is only supported by IE and allows you to target specific versions as well, so it is ideal for hacking in a solution to fix an IE-specific problem.

Comment: Thank you. The truth of the matter is that I am using Openlayers and it wont work for me in IE6-8 and I failed to find out why. I really don't know which capability specifically could be detected to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the parameter like this :

```
<ui:param name="isIE8" value="#{!header['User-Agent'].matches('.*; MSIE [2-8]\\.0.*')}"/>
```

And then conditionally display some code.

With JSF 1.2 and vanilla HTML (no JSF components), you can use :

```
<f:verbatim rendered="#{isIE8}">
    Here is the code for old versions IE, without HTML5, for example
</f:verbatim>
<f:verbatim rendered="#{!isIE8}">
    Here is the code for other browsers
</f:verbatim>
```

With JSF 2.0, 2.2 or for code containing JSF components or EL, use :

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{isIE8}">
    etc.
```